# Looking for Radio Automation Software

Tags: software-recommendation, live, podcast, radio, broadcasting

I am currently planning to run a podcast or a radio show as you prefer, where I intend to broadcast some Skype talking and play some music, live through [Mixlr](http://mixlr.com/). I've been looking for some software that can help me to do this. Something where I can create a playlist that I can set up easily, control mic, have some embedded notes, etc.

I am especially looking for **free software**, but if I get myself into something that fits my needs, then I am willing to spend a few bucks.

I ran into a couple paid solutions:

[ProppFrexx](http://www.proppfrexx.radio42.com/v3/index.html) OnAir, which seems the most complete solution, with tons of options, most of them not really understood by me... Looks very recent, and the free version lets you play for 3 hours, with a random 2kHZ sound playing occasionally.

[SAM Broadcaster](http://spacial.com/sam-broadcaster), which seems to be used by most of the people. Looks like a very simple solution (the free version, at least)

There are other free options, but most of them do not work rather well or are hard to understand and get used to.

My question is then, if there are good free solutions that fit my needs (for Windows and/or eventually Ubuntu) and which. Or paid ones, that are quite simple and easy to manage. Out of curiosity, I would also ask if you know which software big radio stations use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Windows, but for Ubuntu, you could always check out Rivendell.
http://www.rivendellaudio.org/

Answer (score 2):

Can't help with freeware, but i can shed some light on the professional side of things.

At urgent.fm we use [Zenon](http://www.zenon-media.com/) because most commercial stations in Belgium use it, and our station is one of the starting places for people interested into getting into radio work professionally in our region.
That way someone who was trained at our station feels right at home in most commercial settings.

It consists of several soft- and hardware devices that can be tailored to suit to specific needs.

Comment: @AJ Henderson, thanks for correcting my spelling. Is linking to the radio station not allowed because it is seen as a form of advertising? If so i will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: I don't think it is strictly against policy, though we do get a lot of spam.  I removed it since you were a new user and could have been link spam and didn't seem to add anything to the answer.  (Link farming is something spammers sometimes do to raise the search results of a page.  They make hyperlinks on high rank sites to boost a page in Google.)  Since you mentioned your affiliation, if you were an established user, I wouldn't have even thought anything of the link though.

Comment: I can see what you mean, thank you for taking time to explain.